# How To Show The Menu Bar In Slack For Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, slack

I accidentally closed the menu bar in the Slack application for Windows and can't figure out how to show it. How do I show the menu bar again?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Press Alt and the menu bar drops down. If you want it to be there always, click Window > Always Show Menu Bar.

Comment: This option is no longer available.

Comment: The slack application hides (without the aforementioned option even available) the menu bar if it detects Windows 10.  You can fool it into restoring the option for showing the menu again by using the Program Compatibility Assistant (locate SLACK.EXE , right-click for props dialog, go to Compatibility tab, select Win7 mode)